# Numpy: raise ValueError("shape too large to be a matrix.")

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am using a 12x12 numpy matrix, and I am getting "shape too large to be a matrix." My best guess is that numpy "kron" function is making trouble.

Here's my code:

```
    a = np.matrix("0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 0 ")
    a_dag = np.matrix("0 0 0; 1 0 0 ; 0 1 0")
    Sp = np.matrix("0 1; 0 0")
    Sm = np.matrix("0 0; 1 0")
    ...
119 H_I1 = (np.exp(1j*(phi-omega*t))*kron(np.eye(3),Sp,np.eye(2))
120         +np.exp(-1j*(phi-omega*t))*kron(np.eye(3),Sm,np.eye(2)))
121 H_I2 = kron(a,Sp,np.eye(2)) + kron(a_dag,Sm,np.eye(2))
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fyodr/qc_final.py", line 121, in <module>
    H_I2 = kron(a,Sp,np.eye(2)) + kron(a_dag,Sm,np.eye(2))
  File "/home/fyodr/qc_final.py", line 70, in kron
    return np.kron(m[0],kron(m[1:]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 754, in kron
    result = wrapper(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 303, in __array_finalize__
    raise ValueError("shape too large to be a matrix.")
ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I defined kron as

```
def kron(*m):
    if len(m) == 1:
        return m
    else :
        return np.kron(m[0],kron(m[1:]))
```

If np.kron were computing a regular kronecker product, then this should not be a problem.

Comment: What is this `kron`?  You give it 3 arguments, while `np.kron` takes 2.  Give a minimal working (to the error at least) example.  Skip the `H_I1` line if that works.  And evaluate the 2 parts of `H_I2` separately so we know - and you - know which causes the problem.

Comment: As I guessed that `kron` does create a higher dimensional array, 4d in fact.  You need to debug it before using in other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I commented, your `kron` with 3 arguments is unknown.  But if it produces a 3d array as some stage, it could produce your error.

```
In [264]: np.kron(a.A, np.ones((3,3,3))).shape
Out[264]: (3, 9, 9)
```

A 2d array with a 3d returns a 3d array.  But if `a` is a `np.matrix` it tries to convert that to a `matrix` resulting in the error.  `np.matrix` is always 2d.

```
In [265]: np.kron(a, np.ones((3,3,3))).shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
....
ValueError: shape too large to be a matrix.
```

Experienced `numpy` users don't use `np.matrix` unless we really need its features, and can live with its drawbacks.

---

With the `kron` that you added, the recursive step does:

```
In [270]: m = (a, Sp, np.eye(2))
In [271]: kron(m[1:])
Out[271]: 
((matrix([[0, 1],
          [0, 0]]), array([[ 1.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  1.]])),)
In [272]: np.array(_)
Out[272]: 
array([[[[ 0.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 1.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  1.]]]])
In [273]: _.shape
Out[273]: (1, 2, 2, 2)
```

For 2 items, your `kron` returns a nested tuple of arrays.  `np.kron` applies a `np.asanyarray(b)` to that 2nd argument, which results in a 4d array.

Applying your `kron` to  full `*m`, but turning the matrices into arrays:

```
In [275]: kron(a.A, Sp.A, np.eye(2))
Out[275]: 
array([[[[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]]])
In [276]: _.shape
Out[276]: (1, 2, 6, 6)
```

Did you even test the `kron` function by itself?  It should have been debugged before use in a more complicated task.